# Joining two DataFrames on a string column but ignoring accents/diacritics

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have two DataFrames that I want to join based upon a string column but one of them encodes its names with very shoddy unicode support that drops accents and other diacritics:

```
fips = DataFrame(muni=["Adjuntas", "Anasco", "Bayamon", "Mayaguez"], fips=[72001, 72011, 72021, 72097])
pops = DataFrame(muni=["Adjuntas", "Añasco", "Bayamón", "Mayagüez"], pop=[17363, 26161, 169269, 71530])
```

I want to have `leftjoin(pops, fips; on=:muni)` use an approximate equality when joining that handles missing accents and diacritics (but ensures the base character is the same), or, failing that, some sort of ascii-ification string transform on `pops`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
julia> using Unicode

julia> leftjoin(transform(pops,
                          :muni =>
                          ByRow(x -> Unicode.normalize(x, stripmark=true)) =>
                          :muni,
                          copycols=false),
                fips, on=:muni)
4×3 DataFrame
 Row │ muni      pop     fips
     │ String    Int64   Int64?
─────┼──────────────────────────
   1 │ Adjuntas   17363   72001
   2 │ Anasco     26161   72011
   3 │ Bayamon   169269   72021
   4 │ Mayaguez   71530   72097
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! I had found https://stackoverflow.com/a/37511463/176071 and implemented the transliteration of that normalize |> regex workflow, but had missed the much more direct and succinct `stripmark` normalization option.  Thanks!